# Отображается только последний зарегистрированный пользователь

Tags: php

Когда на сайте зарегистрированно 100 пользователей они отображаются нормально, то есть постранично по 10 пользователей на каждой странице. И работает перемещение по страницам, но когда регистрируется 101 пользователь все странички убираются и отображается первый зарегистрированый пользователь, ошибок никаких нет.

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE);
// показать всеx пользователей постранично
$y_users_total = $users->y_users_total();
$page_vars_c = $users->make_page($y_users_total, $users_page, $c);
$y_users_list = $users->y_users_list($page_vars_c[0], $users_page);

$smarty->assign('users', $y_users_list);
$smarty->assign('users_total', $y_users_total);
$smarty->assign('c', $page_vars_c[1]);
$smarty->assign('maxpage_c', $page_vars_c[2]);
$smarty->assign('start_c', $page_vars_c[0]+1);

$smarty->assign('end_c', $page_vars_c[0]+count($y_users_list));

?>
```

Вот так выглядит страничка
[image: alt]

Поиск по id и e-mail работает, пользователи отдельно отображаются

```
 // функция постраничной пагинации
function make_page($total_items, $items_per_page, $p) {

if(($total_items % $items_per_page) != 0) { $maxpage = ($total_items) / $items_per_page + 1; } else { $maxpage = ($total_items) / $items_per_page; }
    $maxpage = (int) $maxpage;
    if($maxpage <= 0) { $maxpage = 1; }
    if($p > $maxpage) { $p = $maxpage; } elseif($p < 1) { $p = 1; }
    $start = ($p - 1) * $items_per_page;
return Array($start, $p, $maxpage);
}
```

Comment: Что такое `$users` и `$users_page`?

Comment: это класс/массив пользователей/страниц работает так: $users-> функция(переменные);

Comment: Вероятно, проблема именно в нём?

Comment: может эта функция? я подгрузил её

Comment: Исходя из функции я $c поменял на $p и все странички отобразились, только не работает перемещение)

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо Андрей за наводку